# phpmyadmin create sequence error

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have an error in creating my database by using the phpmyadmin. I can't create the sequence for my trigger.

```
CreateSequence('workingvisa_seq', 1000, 1)
;


create or replace trigger foreignworker_trig
before insert on foreign_worker
for each row
begin
vwo_ varchar2(4000);
end;
pk__ binary_double;
begin 
select workingvisa_seq.nextval into pk_visa from dual;
if vworker_country='BANGLADESH'then set :new.worker_country = ||('AG',ifnull(pk_visa, '')); 
elseif vworker_country='INDONESIA' then set :new.worker_country = ||('AK',ifnull(pk_visa, ''));
elseif vworker_country='MYANMAR' then set :new.worker_country = ||('B',ifnull(pk_visa, ''));
end if;
end;
```

Here is my error.

> Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'CreateSequence('workingvisa_seq', 1000, 1)' Ã  la ligne 1

Please answer me in English, I don't even know what the error is since I don't understand French.

Comment: It means that you have a syntax error in the createsequence line. What is this createsequence()? This is not standard mysql stuff. You may be trying to execute a non-mysql sql code within mysql. The trigger code seems to be in tsql, which is used by ms sql and not mysql.

Comment: [Documentation for MYSQL Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)